# Comparing string* in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, string, c++17, comparison

Let `a` and `b` be given positive integers . Consider the following C++17 code :

```
string* first;
first = new string[a];
//some definitions

string* second;
second = new string[b];
//some definitions
```

By saying a string `first[i]` is undefined, I mean no definition is ever made to the string `first[i]` after the creation code given above.

I define `first` and `second` to be equal if:

1. `a==b`.
2. `first[i]` and `second[i]` are equivalent for every non-negative integer `i<a`, in the following sense: if `first[i]` is undefined, then so is `second[i]`; if `first[i]` has length `l` (where `l` is a non-negative integer), then `second[i]` has length `l` and `first[i][j]` is the same char as `second[i][j]` for every non-negative integer `j<l`.

In short, I want the most ordinary string equality with the emphasis on comparing the contents rather than the pointers. What is the most appropriate way to do this in C++17? I tried multiple answers and none of them works.

Comment: What does "`first[i]` is null" mean?. `std::string`s cannot be "null", in any sense of this term as used in C++.

Comment: I have modified the sentence to make it more precise. I meant undefined.

Comment: What does "`first[i]` is undefined" mean? That also does not mean anything in C++. In C++ strings cannot be "null" or "undefined".

Comment: I have added the description.

Comment: I think there's a language barrier here. Technical terms, such as "undefined" and "null" have certain, specific meanings in C++ that do not apply here. I suspect that you possibly mean "empty", but I can't assume that. Presuming so: the above description can be, pretty much, directly translated into C++, exactly as is. You should attempt to implement this logical comparison yourself, using your debugger if needed, and ask, specifically, if the resulting code is not working correctly and you cannot figure out why.

Comment: Why on earth are you using manual dynamic memory allocation for this?

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming `string` is `std::string`.

The real solution here would be to use `std::vector<std::string>` rather than managing your own dynamic memory:

```
std::vector<std::string> first;
//some definitions

std::vector<std::string> second;
//some definitions

bool equal = (first == second); // does what you want
```

If, for some reason, you cannot use `std::vector`, the C-style approach would look something like

```
bool are_equal(std::string* first, std::size_t first_size, std::string* second, std::size_t second_size) {
    if (first_size != second_size) return false;
    for (std::size_t idx = 0; idx != first_size; ++idx) {
        if (first[idx] != second[idx]) return false;
    }
    return true;
}

int main() {
    string* first = new string[a];
    //some definitions

    string* second = new string[b];
    //some definitions

    bool equal = are_equal(first, a, second, b);
    return 0;
}
```

With C++20, prefer using `std::span` here

```
bool are_equal(std::span<const std::string> first, std::span<const std::string> second) {
    if (first.size() != second.size()) return false;
    for (std::size_t idx = 0; idx != first.size(); ++idx) {
        if (first[idx] != second[idx]) return false;
    }
    return true;
}

    int main() {
    string* first = new string[a];
    //some definitions

    string* second = new string[b];
    //some definitions

    bool equal = are_equal({first, a}, {second, b});
    return 0;
}
```